# How to get Drawable image name in a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of images in a recycler view.I want to display the name of image used in background. But when i click any image  it returns **"android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@1cca205"** in log.How to display the image name? I want to use this image name in switch case and perform some task.

Main Activity.java

```
public static String[] AddCustomitems = {"Blink single message", "Blink double message", "Message", "Scroll", "Split", "Temp"};
    public static final Integer[] customviewsDrawable = {R.drawable.custom_blink, R.drawable.custom_blink_double, R.drawable.custom_message, R.drawable.custom_scroll, R.drawable.custom_split_double, R.drawable.temp};
    public static final Integer defaultAdd =R.drawable.custom_add;
    ArrayList<ItemModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arrayList.add(new ItemModel(defaultAdd));
        for(int i =0;i<customviewsDrawable.length;i++){
            ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();
            arrayList.add(new ItemModel(customviewsDrawable[i]));
        }
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        //Set RecyclerView type according to intent value
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ItemModel model = arrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        final RecyclerViewHolder mainHolder = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;// holder

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), model.getImage());// This will convert drawbale image into
        // bitmap
        mainHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 330, 500, false));
        mainHolder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("Image name:", String.valueOf(mainHolder.imageview.getDrawable())); 
            }
        });
        setAnimation(holder.cardView, position);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not have a chance to try but it's this should give you a name.

```
mainHolder.imageview.getResources().getResourceName(mainHolder.imageview.getId()))
```

This is only show imageview name.

So i check that and the only way to do this:

```
mainHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 330, 500, false));
mainHolder.imageview.setTag("yourImageName");
        mainHolder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("Image name:", String.valueOf(mainHolder.imageview.getTag("yourImageName");)); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: got **V/Image name:: com.example.parmarravi21.recylerviewtuto:id/image** still missing image name

Comment: i check but you can only do this with the tag. I have updated the code above.

Comment: With the above code i would be setting up all images in a list view with tag "yourImageName". My query is how to uniquely identify name of the image that is present  in recylcerView .Thats how it should be working [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwzrLyNTTu8&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: That's seems not possible. Maybe you change itemmodel, add title string and you set tag with title in onBindViewHolder. But then you can call. Because when you describe a bitmap or drawable, java convert it as reference id. so you do not have a string and you can not call it that way

Comment: implemented the code successfully [link](https://github.com/parmarravi/HorizontalRecyclerView)

Answer (score -1):

Place the image in drawable folder and access it via R.drawable.image_name.